# Automatically update npm version when pull request is merged in bitbucket

Tags: java, git, hook, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

The idea is to trigger `npm version patch` to increase the version from 1.2.3 to 1.2.4 once you press the button of the image:

[image: Merge pull request]

So every change in the develop's branch means a new build version in the application.

I have tried using `.git/hooks/post-merge` and running the command if the merged branch name is develop. It works but only if I perform a merge in the console of visual studio but not when clicking the bitbucket merge button.

I'm also trying to create a java maven plugin with the [developer atlassian SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/) but i'm not getting this working, it's outdated with not too much documentation and i'm not even succeed in the build process.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This should be part of the CI/CD pipeline, rather than sitting in a `git` hook.

On merge to your `master` (assumption) branch, you should have a task within your pipeline that tags the `sha` of `master`. You can easily achieve this with tools such as Travis, CircleCI, Jenkins etc.

Comment: do you have some examples of such config? )